# Link de rotas angular não funciona no bootstrap

Tags: angularjs, bootstrap-3, menu, angular-routes

Pessoa estou com problema no menu. Os link's feitos no Bootstrap não estão trazendo minhas rotas do angular. Se eu colocar o comando na barra de navegação vai de boa. Já pesquisei varias coisa e nada funciona. Se alguém sobeu me ajuda por favor. Obrigado pessoal!

segue código.

```html
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>TonaCraft</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilo.css">
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Crete+Round:400,400italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <script src="angular.js"></script>
    <script src="angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app/modulos/app.js"></script>
    <script src="app/controller/controle.js"></script>
</head>

<body lang="pt-br" ng-app="app">

<!-- Topo Header -->

    <div class="row fundoGrdadiente">
        <div class="col-md-12"> 
            <div class="imgTopoEsqDir noneMobile"><img src="imagens/logoMenu.png" width="100%"> </img></div>
            <div class="imgTopoCentro"><img src="imagens/logo2.png" width="90%" ></img></div>
            <div class="imgTopoEsqDir"><img src="imagens/contatoMail.png" width="100%"
                                onclick="window.open('contato/contato.php' , 'new' , 'toolbar=yes, scrollbars=yes, 
                                resizable=no, top=100, left=500, width=500, height=700')";> </img>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


<!-- MENU -->

<div class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#barraMenu">
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg"><a class="navbar-brand" ng-href="#/principal">TonaCraft</a></div>
      </div>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse rolling-nav" id="barraMenu" >
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav menu"> 
            <li><a ng-href="#/principal">Início</a></li>
            <li><a ng-href="#/comandos">Comandos</a></li>
            <li><a ng-href="#/downloads">Downloads</a></li>
            <li><a ng-href="#/eventos">Eventos</a></li>
            <li><a ng-href="#/cash">Doações</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
   </div>
 </div> 
 <a ng-href="#/principal">principal</a>
 <a ng-href="#/comandos">comandos</a>
 <a ng-href="#/downloads">downloads</a>
 <a ng-href="#/eventos">eventos</a>
 <a ng-href="#/cash">cash</a>
<!-- View Angular -->
<ng-view> </ng-view>

<!--Footer -->
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12" ng-include src="'inc/rodape.inc'"> </div>
</div>


<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script text="javascript" src="myJs.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
</body>
```

MODULO:

```js
 // Carregando o modulo ngRoute
 var app = angular.module('app',['ngRoute']);
  
 app.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider)
 {
   
 /*  // remove o # da url
   $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);*/

   // para a rota '/principal', carregaremos o template principal.html e o controller 'PrincipalCtrl'
   $routeProvider.when('/principal', {
      templateUrl : 'app/views/principal.html',
      controller     : 'PrincipalCtrl',
   })
 
   // para a rota '/comandos', carregaremos o template comandos.html e o controller 'ComandosCtrl'
   $routeProvider.when('/comandos', {
      templateUrl : 'app/views/comandos.html',
      controller  : 'ComandosCtrl',
   })

   // para a rota '/downloads', carregaremos o template downloads.html e o controller 'DownloadsCtrl'
   $routeProvider.when('/downloads', {
      templateUrl : 'app/views/downloads.html',
      controller  : 'DownloadsCtrl',
   })
   
   // para a rota '/eventos', carregaremos o template eventos.html e o controller 'EventosCtrl'
   $routeProvider.when('/eventos', {
      templateUrl : 'app/views/eventos.html',
      controller  : 'EventosCtrl',
   })

   // para a rota '/cash', carregaremos o template cash.html e o controller 'CashCtrl'
   $routeProvider.when('/cash', {
      templateUrl : 'app/views/cash.html',
      controller  : 'CashCtrl',
   })

  /* // caso não seja nenhum desses, redirecione para a rota '/'
   $routeProvider.otherwise ({ redirectTo: '/principal' });*/

   

});
```

CONTROLE

```js
app.controller('PrincipalCtrl', function($rootScope, $location)
{
   $rootScope.activetab = $location.path();
});
 
app.controller('ComandosCtrl', function($rootScope, $location)
{
   $rootScope.activetab = $location.path();
});
 
app.controller('DownloadsCtrl', function($rootScope, $location)
{
   $rootScope.activetab = $location.path();
});

app.controller('EventosCtrl', function($rootScope, $location)
{
   $rootScope.activetab = $location.path();
});
 
app.controller('CashCtrl', function($rootScope, $location)
{
   $rootScope.activetab = $location.path();
});
```

UMA VIEW DE EXEMPLO

```html
  <style>
   .altura300{height:300px;}
   .altura200{height:200px;}

   .backColorPanel{ 
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,0.65) 3%, rgba(28,28,28,0.65) 43%, rgba(68,68,68,0) 100%);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,0.65) 3%,rgba(28,28,28,0.65) 43%,rgba(68,68,68,0) 100%); 
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0,0,0,0.65) 3%,rgba(28,28,28,0.65) 43%,rgba(68,68,68,0) 100%); 
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#a6000000', endColorstr='#00444444',GradientType=0 ); }
   .backColorHeadPanel{ background: rgb(181,189,200); /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(181,189,200,1) 0%, rgba(130,140,149,1) 36%, rgba(40,52,59,1) 95%); /* FF3.6-15 */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(181,189,200,1) 0%,rgba(130,140,149,1) 36%,rgba(40,52,59,1) 95%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(181,189,200,1) 0%,rgba(130,140,149,1) 36%,rgba(40,52,59,1) 95%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#b5bdc8', endColorstr='#28343b',GradientType=0 );}

  </style>
 </head>
 <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="panel panel-default backColorPanel">
    <div class="panel-heading backColorHeadPanel">    
      <h1 class="panel-title text-center">Download do Jogo</h1> 
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
     <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="row">    
       <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="panel panel-default altura300 backColorBodyPanel">
         img download
        </div>
       </div>
       
       <div class="col-md-8">
        <div class="panel panel-default altura300 backColorBodyPanel">
         descrição jogo
        </div>
       </div>   
      </div>  
     </div>
    </div> 
   </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="row">
   <div class="panel panel-default backColorPanel">
    <div class="panel-heading">    
      <h1 class="panel-title text-center">Dicas de Texture</h1>    
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
     <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="panel panel-default altura200 backColorBodyPanel">
          <div class="panel-heading">
         <h3 class="panel-title">Panel title</h3>
          </div>
          <div class="panel-body">
         Panel content
          </div>
        </div>
       </div>

       <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="panel panel-default altura200 backColorBodyPanel">
          <div class="panel-heading">
         <h3 class="panel-title">Panel title</h3>
          </div>
          <div class="panel-body">
         Panel content
          </div>
        </div>
       </div>

       <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="panel panel-default altura200 backColorBodyPanel">
          <div class="panel-heading">
         <h3 class="panel-title">Panel title</h3>
          </div>
          <div class="panel-body">
         Panel content
          </div>
        </div>
       </div>

       <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="panel panel-default altura200 backColorBodyPanel">
          <div class="panel-heading">
         <h3 class="panel-title">Panel title</h3>
          </div>
          <div class="panel-body">
         Panel content
          </div>
        </div>
       </div>

      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>

 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Tenta algo assim nos links:

```
<a ng-class="isActive('#seuLink')" href="#seuLink">Link</a>
```

Não coloque a barra antes, mesmo que no seu app.js tenha lá a barra.

**Exemplo:**

No seu app.js tem o seguinte código

```
.when('/sobre',{
    templateUrl: "templates/sobre.html",
})
```

No link ficaria assim:

```
<a ng-class="isActive('#sobre')" href="#sobre">Sobre</a>
```

Comment: Obrigado amigo! Funcionou!

Comment: Se puder marcar como correta a resposta, agradeço

Answer (score 0):

- Para funcionar da forma como você está implementando agora basta substituir o `ng-href` pelo `href`.

  ```
      <li><a href="#/principal">Início</a></li>
      <li><a href="#/comandos">Comandos</a></li>
      <li><a href="#/downloads">Downloads</a></li>
      <li><a href="#/eventos">Eventos</a></li>
      <li><a href="#/cash">Doações</a></li>
  ```

Para funcionar com `ng-href` é preciso ter uma variável carregada no `$scope`, Ex:

### Controller

```
       $scope.meuLink = '/cash';
```

### View

```
      <a ng-href="#/{{meuLink}}"/>Ir ao faz me rir</a>
```